# How to act smartly so that people don't take you for granted?

Tags: psychology, social-ethics, emotions, human-nature

In our daily life, we meet some people & friends who will make you part of their tough times (share about tough days/Seek support and help) but They don't make you part of his/her happy times (Happy days/Events). How should we view it & deal with it?

Comment: Take a look at the Philosophy [Tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour). It sets out some ways in which you can ensure your question meets guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

View it without the lens of friendship. If a person seeks you out only when they need help, and offer nothing in return (the sharing of the good times, as you put it) then they are *using you* as support. If you are okay with this kind of one-sided relationship, then you need to take no further action. If you aren't okay with it, the solution I use personally is to **limit the amount of assistance given to a level where it is not a personal burden.**

The way I remember this strategy is a bit odd: there's a snowman that you can talk to in one of the Animal Crossing games that says "If there's anything I can do to help you, anything at all, and I can do it without moving from this exact spot, please let me know." In short, if I can help without going out of my way, I'm happy to, but don't ask for more.